# Move_base usage

Tags: navigation, move-base

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,

I want to work with move_base package and I don't know how to achieve certain objectives.

I want to pause the pause the movement (given a goal I want to pause the movement until I receive a signal without forgetting the goal). By the time the signal is received, the robot shall continue its movement towards the goal.

Thank you

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/196559/move_base-usage/) by [arenillas](https://answers.ros.org/users/15376/arenillas/) on ROS Answers with karma: 223 on 2014-11-03

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

you could use the actionlib and cancel the goal (instead of pause). to continue just send the same goal again.

see http://wiki.ros.org/move_base [1.1.2 Action API]

---

Originally posted by [lebowski](https://answers.ros.org/users/20622/lebowski/) with karma: 146 on 2014-11-03

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1